# Get XML result from HTML using RESTAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am facing some situation where I thought the things will be pretty trivial , as usual not so much.

I am fetching a GET call to a site , which returns the result as HTML, with a lot of

```
RequestSpecification requestSpecification = initRequest()
            .basePath("myPathHere");

    Response response = requestSpecification.get().then().contentType(ContentType.HTML)
            .extract().response();
```

so far everything Is ok, but then when I try to convert that to XML it gives me empty result.

I tried

```
XmlPath htmlPath = new XmlPath(CompatibilityMode.XML, response.getBody().asString());
```

also

```
XmlPath htmlPath = new XmlPath(CompatibilityMode.HTML, response.getBody().asString());
```

I checked google on the matter is very chaotic, that should be quite easy, but why its not ?

Comment: Dis you try; `XmlPath path = response.xmlPath();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
RequestSpecification requestSpecification = initRequest()
                                              .basePath("myPathHere");

XmlPath htmlPath = requestSpecification
                      .get()
                      .xmlPath();
```

Or this:

```java
RequestSpecification requestSpecification = initRequest()
                                              .basePath("myPathHere");

XmlPath htmlPath = requestSpecification
                      .get()
                      .then()
                      .extract()
                         .path('');
```